# Use functions from separate .cpp file by yii framework

Tags: php, c++, rpc

My client gave me a c++ library to use in yii project. C++ library has main.cpp in src folder which has certain functions. I want to use that functions in my yii framework.
Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think it's even possible? (without creating a custom extension that will expose that c++ library functions into php)

Comment: I don't know its possible or not, Because i am new in yii. I read about custom extension but don't know how to create them.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible; you need a RPC([Remote Procedure Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)) framework to call cross platform procedures/functions

There is PHP -> C++ framework  called [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) developed by Apache Foundation it was originally written by Facebook for doing this sort of calls.

```
Thrift is a software framework for scalable cross-language services development. 
It combines a software stack with a code generation engine to build services 
that work efficiently and seamlessly between C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, 
Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, Smalltalk, and OCaml and Delphi and 
other languages.
```

RPC is a fairly advanced programming paradigm, you need to be able to understand both languages well. It requires some config and setup

Alternatively you can use a compiled version of your C++ library and use only the exposed API via system shell calls. Debugging is easier in that scenario, however this may or may not be possible depending on the way your library is structured and whether there is stable exposed API etc

Comment: for this we required thrift server?